# ADAL4J in java application not working for native application(Azure Active Directory) when Multi Factor Authentication is enabled

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

Hi We have created a native application in AAD and we are trying to get the access token from Azure using Adal4j in our java application following is the snippet

```
AuthenticationContext authContext;
    AuthenticationResult authResult;
    String loginUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+TENANTID+"/oauth2/authorize";
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(loginUrl, false, service);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", clientId, username,password, null);
    authResult = future.get();
    System.out.println("Token :"+authResult.getAccessToken());
```

but recently our organisation  has enabled multi factor authentication and since then we are getting the below error.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013'.\r\nTrace ID: c0ac222e-5a9b-417e-8360-d42712f43c00\r\nCorrelation ID: 96cc11c4-3196-448d-a416-a9373b8059a6\r\nTimestamp: 2018-08-13 12:57:59Z","error":"interaction_required"}

Please help me on how i can fix this error
ADAL4j version is 1.1.3

I have created app registrations using below
[image][image][image]

Please let me know what im missing as i see it is displaying for your account bt not for my account. MFA is enabled for my tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please help me on how i can fix this error ADAL4j version is 1.1.3

If the user is enabled with [multi factor authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks), we **can't** use that to get access token to access the resource directly.

> **The security of two-step verification lies in its layered approach**. Compromising multiple authentication factors presents a significant challenge for attackers. Even if an attacker manages to learn the user's password, it is useless without also having possession of the additional authentication method. It works by requiring two or more of the following authentication methods:
>
> - Something you know (typically a password)
> - Something you have (a trusted device that is not easily duplicated, like a phone)
> - Something you are (biometrics)

---

> we are trying to get the access token from Azure using Adal4j in our java application

You could registry an Azure AD web application and use the following way to instead of using the username and password to get the access token. How to registry Azure AD webapp and get the secret key from it, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

```
String resourceUrl = "https://management.azure.com";
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
// Acquire Token
Future<AuthenticationResult> result = context.acquireToken(
resourceUrl,
new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET),
null
);
String token = result.get().getAccessToken();
```

**Update:**

Add the demo code for geting subscription. If you get the empty list means that there is no subscription with your tenant.

```
String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
String resourceUrl = "https://management.azure.com";
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
    // Acquire Token
Future<AuthenticationResult> result = context.acquireToken(
            resourceUrl,
         new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET),
    null
    );
String token = result.get().getAccessToken();
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01");
request.addHeader("Authorization",result.get().getAccessTokenType()+ " "+ result.get().getAccessToken());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
// Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String.
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
System.out.println(content);
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

**Update2:**

How to switch the directory with Azure portal.

[image]

Try it with [List subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) Rest API directly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for  the reply using the above code i'll get the access token but when i try to get the subscriptions using the below it returns empty list.                         GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/?api-version=2016-03-30               O/p:{"value":[]}

Comment: Would you mind sharing the get subscriptions code or  rest api endpoint?

Comment: Im calling "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/?api-version=2016-03-30" by passing header key "Authorization" header value as "bearer TOKEN"

Comment: It should work, please make sure that there is a subscription with your tenant. If you get the empty list means that there is no subscription with your tenant.

Comment: i have edited my question and added the way i have registered an app, also the my subscriptions falls under the tenant id but MFA is enabled in tenant i think that is the issue.

Comment: If you are using clientid and secret way to get access token, there is no relationship with MFA. I assume that you have mutiple tenants, if it is that case, you could switch the tenant and try it again. How to switch directory, please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: You also could try it with Azure list subscription Rest API directly. For more information, please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: i tried the above but still its not working we have only one tenant for entire organization i.e it may contain 100's of subscriptions and i have contributor access to only one subscription .........how ever since i have logged in azure when i do try it from this link which u mentioned "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list" it is working but not with the code.

Comment: `i tried the above but still its not working we have only one tenant for entire organization` Is there any exception?